# Como aplicar várias funções ao mesmo objeto?

Tags: r, programação-funcional

Como é possível, no `R`, aplicar várias funções ao mesmo objeto?

**Exemplo:**

Digamos que eu tenha um vetor `x`.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10)
x
# [1] -0.56047565 -0.23017749  1.55870831  0.07050839  0.12928774
# [6]  1.71506499  0.46091621 -1.26506123 -0.68685285 -0.44566197
```

E eu preciso aplicar um série de funções sobre este vetor. Digamos, apenas para fins de exemplo que estas funções fossem: média, desvio padrão, mínimo e máximo.

A forma mais ingênua de fazer isso é chamar cada função separadamente.

```
mean(x)
# [1] 0.07462564
sd(x)
# [1] 0.9537841
max(x)
# [1] 1.715065
min(x)
# [1] -1.265061
```

Como eu poderia abstrair esses quatro chamados por apenas um que fosse mais flexível?

**Edição**

A ideia é as funções aplicadas possam ser definidas na hora, excluindo a função `min()` ou adicionando a função `median()`, por exemplo, conforme a necessidade do momento.

Um `map` aplica uma função a vários valores. A dúvida aqui é como fazer o contrário, como aplicar várias funções em um valor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A função R base `Map` pode fazer o que quer.
Primeiro vou refazer os dados, uma vez que também vou usar uma lista de vetores, não só uma lista de funções.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- x
is.na(y) <- sample(10, 3)
```

Agora, o `Map` vai aplicar várias funções aos vetores `x` e `y`, um de cada vez.

```
Map(function(f, x, ...){f(x, ...)}, list(mean, sd, median), list(x), na.rm = TRUE)
Map(function(f, x, ...){f(x, ...)}, list(mean, sd, median), list(y), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Isto pode ser escrito numa função mais geral, que permita como segundo argumento uma lista de vetores.

```
MapFuns <- function(fun.list, object, ...){
  if(is.list(object)){
    lapply(object, function(x)
      Map(function(f, x, ...){f(x, ...)}, fun.list, list(x), ...)
    )
  }else{
    Map(function(f, x, ...){f(x, ...)}, fun.list, list(object), ...)
  }
}

flist <- list(mean, sd, median)
MapFuns(flist, x)
MapFuns(flist, list(x, y))
MapFuns(flist, list(x, y), na.rm = TRUE)
```

E também resulta com objetos mais complexos.

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = rep(c("a", "b"), 5), X = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(A = rep(c("a", "b"), 5), X = rnorm(10))

groupMean <- function(DF){
  tapply(DF[[2]], DF[[1]], mean, na.rm = TRUE)
}

groupMean2 <- function(DF){
  aggregate(DF[[2]], by = list(DF[[1]]), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
}

MapFuns(list(groupMean, groupMean2), list(df1, df2))
```

Answer (score 5):

É só criar uma `function` utilizando a função `combine` (`c`):

```
fun1<-function(x){
    c(mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x),min=min(x),max=max(x))
}
```

Para, após, aplicar essa `function` sobre o objeto desejado:

```
fun1(x)
       mean          sd         min         max 
 0.07462564  0.95378405 -1.26506123  1.71506499
```

**Ponto importante:**

E se no objeto existir *missings* (`NA`)? Nesta situação, tal função não se aplicaria (nem mesmo funções anônimas funcionariam):

```
y<-c(2,3,NA,5,6,7,8,NA)

mean(y)
[1] NA
sd(y)
[1] NA
min(y)
[1] NA
max(y)
[1] NA

fun1(y)
mean   sd  min  max 
NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Quando isso ocorre, deve-se inserir o argumento `na.rm=TRUE`.

```
mean(y,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 5.166667
```

Dentro da `function`, o ajuste poderia ser feito assim:

```
fun2<-function(x){
  funs=c(mean=mean,sd=sd,min=min,max=max)
         lapply(funs,function(f)f(x,na.rm=TRUE))
}

fun2(y)    

$`mean`
[1] 5.166667

$sd
[1] 2.316607

$min
[1] 2

$max
[1] 8
```

Ou, use `sapply` para emitir um vetor como resultado:

```
fun3<-function(x){
  funs=c(mean=mean,sd=sd,min=min,max=max)
         sapply(funs,function(f)f(x,na.rm=TRUE))
}

fun3(y)
mean       sd      min      max 
5.166667 2.316607 2.000000 8.000000
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Mas vou editar a pergunta. Pelo jeito não deixei claro que as funções elencadas são só exemplos. A ideia é que as funções entrem como argumento da função.

Comment: O que desejo é um *function operator*

Answer (score 5):

Dentro do [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) é possível *invocar* várias funções com `invoke_map()` e seus variantes.

O `invoke_map` tem três componentes básicos:

1. `.f`: Uma lista com as funções (os objetos mesmo e não seus nomes como *string*) que serão invocadas
2. `.x`: Uma lista com os objetos que serão passados para cada função. Caso `.x` seja uma lista de tamanho um, ela é reciclada e todas as funções são aplicadas a ela.
3. `...`: Outros argumentos que possam ser passados às funções.

Dessa forma temos, por exemplo

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10)
funcoes <- list(media = mean, maximo = max)

library(purrr)

invoke_map(funcoes, list(x))
# $`media`
# [1] -0.5604756

# $maximo
# [1] 1.715065
```

Neste sentido, `invoke()` é o contrário de `map()`.

As funções tipo `invoke_map_*` tem as mesmas variações que as `map_*` que fazem a coerção da saída para aquele tipo. Assim é possível converter o resultado num vetor numérico ou numa tabela, por exemplo, da forma que segue.

```
invoke_map_dbl(funcoes, list(x))
#      media     maximo 
# -0.5604756  1.7150650 

invoke_map_df(funcoes, list(x))
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#    media maximo
#    <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 -0.560   1.72
```

Usado o vetor proposto pelo @Rui, é possível demonstrar duas formas de passar os argumentos para `invoke_map()`. Na primeira delas, o argumento `na.rm` é incluído via `...`. Na segunda ele é oferecido dentro da lista de argumentos que serão passados, ou seja, no `.x`.

```
y <- x
is.na(y) <- sample(10, 3)

invoke_map(funcoes, list(y), na.rm = TRUE)
# $`media`
# [1] -0.5604756
# 
# $maximo
# [1] 1.558708

invoke_map(funcoes, list(list(x = y, na.rm = TRUE)))
# $`media`
# [1] -0.1061246
# 
# $maximo
# [1] 1.558708
```

Comment: Por que fez a pergunta se já sabia a resposta?

Comment: Por que outras pessoas podem ter a dúvida. Assim vamos produzindo material sobre `R` em português para futuros leitores

Comment: Entendo, mas então é importante que você explicite isso na sua pergunta e dê a sua resposta dentro da pergunta.

Comment: Eu não teria respondido caso alguém tivesse apresentado o purrr. Sei que a comunidade tem pessoas que conhecem o pacote melhor que eu e poderiam ter respondido a questão

Comment: Além disso, essa resposta só complementa as demais com outra abordagem

Comment: Ainda assim, poderia ter dado a sua resposta e na pergunta ter explicitado como pode melhorá-la.

Comment: @JdeMello leitura recomendada: Discussão no Meta sobre [Responder sua própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422/)

Answer (score 4):

Podemos criar uma função usando como argumento uma ellipsis (`...`).

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10)

myFun <- function(x, ...){
  funs <- list(...)
  res <- vector("list", length = length(funs))
  for(i in seq_along(funs)){
    f <- match.fun(funs[[i]])
    res[[i]] <- f(x)
    rm(f)
  }
  rm(i)
  names(res) <- unlist(funs)
  return(res)
}
```

Um exemplo:

```
> myFun(x, "mean", "median", "sd", "max", "min", "round")
$`mean`
[1] 0.07462564

$median
[1] -0.07983455

$sd
[1] 0.9537841

$max
[1] 1.715065

$min
[1] -1.265061

$round
 [1] -1  0  2  0  0  2  0 -1 -1  0
```

Em `myFun`, o argumento `...` pode receber diversos argumentos dentro dele. Para poder usar os argumentos em `...`, crie uma lista com tais argumentos em `...`:

```
myFun <- function(x, ...){
  funs <- list(...) # passe para uma lista
  return(funs)
}
```

Veja que nessa versão parcial de `myFun`, o objeto a ser retornado será uma lista com os argumentos dados em `...`:

```
> myFun(x, "a", "b", mean)
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[3]]
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("mean")
<bytecode: 0x000000000cc43678>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Agora o problema é em usar esses objetos na lista para fazer as operações necessárias. No caso da sua pergunta, você quer fazer operações em `x` baseado nos argumentos dados em `...` que por sua vez são funções. Isso é feito com a função `match.fun()`:

> Description
>
> When called inside functions that take a function as argument, extract the desired function object while avoiding undesired matching to objects of other types.

Essa função é feita para ser usada dentro de outra função, uma vez que:

> `match.fun` is not intended to be used at the top level since it will perform matching in the parent of the caller.

#### `na.rm = T`

Caso você queira usar argumentos opcionais nas funções contidas em `...` como `na.rm = T`, podemos construir uma condição em `if` dentro do loop:

```
myFun <- function(x, ..., na.rm = F){
  funs <- list(...)
  res <- vector("list", length = length(funs))
  for(i in seq_along(funs)){
    f <- match.fun(funs[[i]])
    res[[i]] <- try(f(x, na.rm = na.rm), silent = T) # executar função com argumento na.rm
    if(inherits(res[[i]], "try-error")) res[[i]] <- f(x) # em caso de erro, re execute-a sem o argumento na.rm...
    rm(f)
  }
  rm(i)
  names(res) <- unlist(funs)
  return(res)
}

x <- c(x, NA)
```

Resultado:

```
> myFun(x, "mean", "round")
$`mean`
[1] NA

$round
 [1] -1  0  2  0  0  2  0 -1 -1  0 NA

> myFun(x, "mean", "round", na.rm = T) # com na.rm =T 
$`mean`
[1] 0.07462564

$round
 [1] -1  0  2  0  0  2  0 -1 -1  0 NA
```